# combine two sed commands

Tags: sed

how to combine the below sed commands in Linux

```
sed -rn 's/.*MsgFlow="([^"]*)".*/\1/p'  ADVQCC_OUTPUT_BRK1
```

and

```
sed -n 's:.*<ProcessDtm>\(.*\)</ProcessDtm>.*:\1:p' ADVQCC_OUTPUT_BRK1
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show input file and desired output?

Comment: looks like you are trying to parse xml/html content. Post your input file content. sed is NOT a proper tool for such case

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can simply concatenate `sed` commands like several `s` commands with an embedded semicolon:

```
sed 's/some/another/;s/stuff/thing/'
```

In your case, one command uses *extended regular expressions* (ERE), the other *basic regular expressions*, so you need to convert one or the other:

```
sed -n 's/.*MsgFlow="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p;s:.*<ProcessDtm>\(.*\)</ProcessDtm>.*:\1:p' ADVQCC_OUTPUT_BRK1
```

or with ERE:

```
sed -En 's/.*MsgFlow="([^"]*)".*/\1/p;s:.*<ProcessDtm>(.*)</ProcessDtm>.*:\1:p' ADVQCC_OUTPUT_BRK1
```

Remark: I changed `-r` to `-E` for selecting ERE, because this is understood by more versions of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more closer variant of two command combination will be (POSIXly):

```
sed -ne 's/.*MsgFlow=\"\([^"]*\)\".*/\1/p' -ne 's/.*<ProcessDtm>\\\(.*\\\)<\/ProcessDtm>.*/\1/p' ADVQCC_OUTPUT_BRK1
```

Or simpliest:

```
sed -e 's/.*MsgFlow=\"\([^"]*\)\".*/\1/' -e 's/.*<ProcessDtm>\\\(.*\\\)<\/ProcessDtm>.*/\1/' ADVQCC_OUTPUT_BRK1
```

But i need input example to get more exact result.

Comment: Why are you escaping double quotes inside the single quote script? Why those `\\\`?